Error running Docker with FastAPI: Problem finding the main module
everyone. I'm having a problem with Docker, I want my backend application to run through Docker, but I'm always getting the same error.
backend | ERROR:  Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main".

I defined my docker image like this

`FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]`

I don't find the error because my directory is organized the way it should be.
|- src
    |- assets
        |- images
            |- apple
                - apple.png
            |- asus
                - asus.png
            |- Dell
                - Dell.png
            |- lenovo
                - lenovo.png
    |- backend
        |- app
            |- database
                |- models 
                    - models.py
                - database.py
            |- routers
                - getdomain.py
                - getregister.py
                - getlogin.py
                - index.py
                - cadastro_ativos.py
                - controle.py
                - not_ring.py
                - prediction_st.py 
        |- env
        |- media
            |- profile_pictures
        - main.py
        - Dockerfile
        - requirements.txt

Can someone help me?
Problem finding the main module

You might want to fix your formatting. It's unclear where main.py is. Also, where is it in relation to your Dockerfile? Reduce it to a minimal example and you'll probably find your issue.

Depending on where your Dockerfile is in your structure, which is unclear, you might need to add the path to the module like so:
CMD ["uvicorn", "backend.app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]`

This question might be helpful too.
